# Repeat div, or jumping back to the top of the page when you reach the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-loop

I am trying to make a endless movable window much like Google maps.

http://mondieu-bureau.nu/bureau/

I have made it possible to drag around in a bigger window but I need to somehow make and endless scroll either horizontally or vertically, preferably both. Much like http://unfold.no/, it jumps back to top when you reach the bottom but I can't really figure out how. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1) {
       $(window).scrollTop(0);
   }
});
```

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/a6o5cybs/)**

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for the reply! I have now added the script in several ways but nothing really happens.

Comment: Probably you have to add an "onload" function to make it work.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: Np. glad I could help... (marking the answer as acepted would be welcome thoug)

Comment: <body  onload="$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1) {
       $(window).scrollTop(0);
   }
});">